# query in mysql gives 0 result if one of tables is empty

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause, exists, cross-join

I have these 3 tables:

```
create table reports(id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,name varchar(255)not null,public_access tinyint not null,primary key (id));
create table report_users(id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,report_id int not null,user_id int not null,primary key (id),foreign key (report_id) references reports(id));
create table report_groups(id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,report_id int not null,group_id int not null,primary key (id),foreign key (report_id) references reports(id));
```

I want to get rows from reports-table where at least one of the following criteria is true:

```
1 - The field public_access is true
2 - The report is in the related table report_users with in parameter user_id 
3 - The report is in the related table report_groups with in parameter group_id
```

First I create a new report with public access:

```
insert into reports values(null, 'report 1 open to all', 1);
```

Then another report only to be accessed by user_id = 1:

```
insert into reports values(null, 'report 2 only for user_id 1', 0);
insert into report_users values(null, 2, 1);
```

Then another report only to be accessed by group_id = 1

```
insert into reports values(null, 'report 3 only for group_id 1', 0);
insert into report_groups values(null, 3, 1);
```

Now, I have 3 rows: one accessible by everybody, one only by user_id = 1 and one only for group_id=1.

Give me all the rows for user_id = 1:

```
select reports.* 
from reports, report_users,report_groups
where 
reports.public_access = 1
or
(report_users.report_id = reports.id and report_users.user_id = 1)
or
(report_groups.report_id = reports.id and report_groups.group_id = 5)
;
```

I get 2 rows. It works.

Give me all the rows for group_id = 1:

```
select reports.* 
from reports, report_users,report_groups
where 
reports.public_access = 1
or
(report_users.report_id = reports.id and report_users.user_id = 4)
or
(report_groups.report_id = reports.id and report_groups.group_id = 1)
;
```

I get 2 rows. It works.

But. If report_users or report_groups are empty, I get no result. I run this query first:

```
truncate table report_groups;
```

When I run the same query as before, I get an empty set. Why? Actually it looks like it does not make any difference the user_id and group_id I send in. I will always get 0 rows.

To me it looks like just because one of the two tables are empty, I do not get any result.
Is it something wrong with the query itself?

Comment: It's `YEAR(CURDATE())`, the **ANSI-92** explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1992) as A_Very_Long_Time`, it's long past time you adopted it. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: For future reference, when asking a SQL based question, its really helpful to us for you to build a quick [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rl-vApZf) Like this, its quick and easy

Comment: I think you need to change your implicit join syntax to left joins where the conditions for the users and groups tables are moved into the join conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing with this line:

```
from reports, report_users,report_groups
```

is a (old style) `CROSS JOIN` of the 3 tables, which means that if one of the tables is empty then the result is also empty.

Instead use `EXISTS`:

```
select r.* 
from reports r
where r.public_access = 1
   or exists (select * from report_users u where u.report_id = r.id and u.user_id = ?)
   or exists (select * from report_groups g where g.report_id = r.id and g.group_id = ?);
```